# Flutter smooth scroll extra scrolling i mean

Tags: flutter

How to create flutter smooth extra[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmffZ.jpg) scroll view

Comment: Please Provide code to help understand the problem.

Comment: Or use the SingleChildScrollView widgit https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein/listview-and-singlechildscrollview-widgets-in-flutter-b2d794ed93a8